# How to build a WinUI 3 app using .NET 6 in an AzureDevops pipeline? Getting: error NETSDK1095

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I have a blank WinUI3 desktop app:

[image: Visual Studio project template]

I would like to build this app in an AzureDevops build pipeline:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

variables:
  solution: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/apps/windows/WinUI3VS2022NET6BlankApp/WinUI3VS2022NET6BlankApp.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'x64'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: Use .NET 6.0
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '6.0.x'

- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 1

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

# Failure here :D
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:PublishReadyToRun=false'
```

I'm getting this error:

C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(293,5): **error NETSDK1095: Optimizing assemblies for performance is not supported for the selected target platform or architecture. Please verify you are using a supported runtime identifier, or set the PublishReadyToRun property to false.** [D:\a\1\s\apps\windows\WinUI3VS2022NET6BlankApp\WinUI3VS2022NET6BlankApp\WinUI3VS2022NET6BlankApp\WinUI3VS2022NET6BlankApp.csproj]

I have tried setting PublishReadyToRun to false in the .csproj and .wapproj files, without luck.

The app builds fine locally with Visual Studio 2022.

Any ideas how I can build this blank WinUI 3 app in AzureDevops?

Comment: Did you extend your pipeline to also package the output and add it as artificats? I cannot find a single documentation for this for Win UI 3 (for Azure Devops).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the correct place to disable `PublishReadyToRun` is in the:

```
Properties/PublishProfile/<profile name>.pubxml
```

file instead of the .csproj file.

Comment: Were you able to deploy this build to the Windows Store? How do you distribute the built version?